# Fix GRUB to boot Windows after deleting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mount

So I accidentally screwed up my GRUB installation and I get "grub rescue>" whenever I boot up.

I had two HDs. HD1 had Windows installed and was my primary boot device. HD2 had a 50GB partition of Ubuntu and the rest was storage. I decided I want Ubuntu as my primary operating system and I want Windows on HD2 so I backed up the storage and reformatted HD2, deleting Ubuntu. But I guess I deleted my GRUB installation because apparently GRUB isn't working now.

I want to install Ubuntu where Windows is now, but I'm not ready to do that yet - I need to get into Windows to back up my stuff.

edit:

I decided to install Ubuntu over Windows on HD1 hoping that would fix it. But when it got to installing grub it gave me an error and froze up. I had to manual restart and the boot menu popped up again. I decided to try to install Ubuntu to HD2 and it worked.

Okay and then the computer restarted and the boot menu popped up again. I decided to try to install it on HD1 to see if I got the same error. The installation worked and I didn't get any errors. So then I clicked reboot and pulled out the USB.

Okay.. so the issue now is my computer is just showing a black screen on startup with a flashing cursor in the top left.

edit2:

Okay now the boot-repair utility looks like it fixed it. Just ran it off of a live session. I'm worried about formatting HD2 now because I don't actually want Ubuntu there.

final edit:

Okay I formatted HD2. Got the same error. Booted live disk and ran boot repair. Problem is fixed.

Comment: I've already looked at that, that's the one where they say mount your partition

Comment: I have a Ubuntu USB disk which I'm running "Try Ubuntu" from. So I don't really have a root partition. All I have is a Windows partition that I don't know how to access.

Comment: So you want to install Ubuntu right? Just install Ubuntu and it will install GRUB. Follow the normal instructions for dual-boot.

Comment: I want to install Ubuntu where Windows is at but I'm not ready to overwrite my Windows yet. Is there any way I can access my Windows so that I can back up my stuff?

Comment: oh I see! I'm sorry I didn't get it... I'll try to edit your post to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

For posterity in answer to the original question: Use Boot-Repair to install a Windows MBR
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Getting Boot-Repair

1st option : get a disk including Boot-Repair

The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to create a disk containing the tool (eg Boot-Repair-Disk, a disk starting Boot-Repair automatically), and boot on it.

Remark : it is recommended to install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer). Do not burn it on a DVD if your computer has Windows8 pre-installed, or if your boot is in EFI mode